# On Chrome, neither the tags nor the Captcha are working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I can't post a question whether standard or Meta using Chrome, Using IExplorer now. Nearly everything on StackExchange doesn't work- no response at all. The top bar doesn't respond. The tags don't respond. Only direct links. The login falls out. I have Japanese version Windows 7. Is it related to deleting cookies or adding Grammarly addin ?

Comment: What error/s are you getting? What version of Chrome? What version of Windows?

Comment: @Oded I don't know if it's related, but earlier today chocolate complained in chat that she was unable to vote on posts or comments on meta using Chrome: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34059749#34059749

Comment: @snailplane - very strange. I am on Chrome too, not having problems. Could be that they are having problems with some JavaScript files not being run properly (either due to ISP shenanigans or an ad blocker blocking too much).

Comment: @Oded I was able to post [a question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/test-question-will-be-deleted) and upvote your comment and a post. Everything seems fine for me (Chrome 55.0.2883.87 on Win7).

Comment: Looks like its Grammarly since I just used the Chrome Cleanup tool